# Performing a one sample t-test with `scipy.stats.ttest_1samp` gives unexpected p_value

Tags: t-test, p-value

I have a model metric (a single value) and a list of sample metrics from benchmark quasi-random models that I would like to do a t-test on to figure out if the model metric result is significantly different from the benchmark models.

I'm using `scipy.stats.ttest_1samp` in python the following way:

```py
ttest_1samp(
        benchmark_results,
        popmean=model_result,
        nan_policy="omit",
    )
```

I get a `p_value` of `0.0024486583942848273` for

example benchmark values = `[-2.6587927988135363, -4.219791925659022, -3.7195390919875226, -1.9198428989686267, 8.959800206295721, -1.2390019649628492, -6.419847829319147, 2.079809995995885, -2.4996800021022114, 0.9806769354933076, -2.1999999999999797, -2.819983152624328, 4.479587456341028, 1.81955840497261,...]`, and

example model result = `0.7004308979742246`.

`len(benchmark_results) == 200`.

Here is the distribution plotted out, which indicates that the null_hypothesis cannot be rejected, yet if I go with alpha = 0.01, the null-hypothesis is rejected (`0.01 > 0.0024486583942848273`):

[image: sample distribution vs population mean]

I have tried the following:

- setting `alternative = 'less'`
- scaling the values (benchmark result and model results jointly) with sklearn's `minmaxscaler`. I have done this because my values can be very small and I thought there might be a numerical unstability.

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I might have not been clear. I have a kappa score of my model eg.: 0.09 and kappa scores from benchmark models eg.: [-0.1, 0.2, ...]. I'd like to know if the p_value of the t_test is below the significance level. I get very small p_values even when my model kappa is very close to the benchmark model distribution mean.

Comment: Welcome to CV. What exactly is your question? Why do you think you are doing anything wrong?

Comment: @semyd Why do you think the graph "indicates that the null_hypothesis cannot be rejected"? A difference can be negligible, even of no interest at all, and still have a very small p-value attached to it.

Comment: My assumption is that the p_value would be small if my value would be at the tail of the sample distribution. The graph shows that my value is not at either ends of the tail, but my p_value is still small. Can it be that this is not the case because N(Sample) is pretty small (200)?

Comment: On your graph, the red line shows a positive value for the population mean (a bit above zero), while in your code it is a negative value (-0.0022662986187913514). You got something mixed up at some point in your data, or it is unclear what your graph is showing.

Comment: Sorry, this was from a different run, I will update the graph.

Comment: The code still does not match the graph. With a value of 0.006265..., your red line should be much further from 0 than that. Look where "0.005" is located on the x axis.

Comment: I have rerun the code and updated all the example values and the graph

Comment: This question has occurred before. Your intuition based on the graph looks at the population distribution, but that is different from the (estimated) distribution of the sample mean which is what is used to do inference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comment section, you wrote:

> My assumption is that the p_value would be small if my value would be
> at the tail of the sample distribution.

The difference between the sample mean and the expected mean is not enough to tell if we can expect a small p-value or not. If the sample size is big enough, you can have a negligible difference between the two means, and still have a really small p-value.

It looks like you're mixing up the empirical distribution of the sample values with the distribution of the [*t*-statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-statistic) if you repeated your experiment a lof of times.

As an example, let's say we want to test a sample against a hypothesized mean of **0.4**. This sample of 200 observations we collected happens to have a mean of $\approx 0.07$. In reality, the sample comes from a normally distributed population, with a mean value of **0** and a standard deviation of 1.

Here's a graph showing the distribution of the 200 observations from this random sample. We see the histogram and the density plot from this empirical distribution. The red vertical line shows the expected mean (0.4), and the blue vertical line shows sample mean (0.07). We see that 0.4 is much closer to 0 than it is to the tail of this empirical distribution.

[image: Distribution plot (histogram and density) of values from a random sample taken from a normally distributed population with a mean of 0 and a standard deviation of 0. The sample mean is 0.07. The hypothesized mean we expect (0.4) appears much closer to 0 than it is to the tail of this empirical distribution.]

Here is some Python code to replicate the graph, if you want:

```
import scipy
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(0)
pop_mean = 0.4
sample_size=200
sample = np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=sample_size)
ax= sns.distplot(sample)
plt.axvline(pop_mean, color="red")
plt.axvline(sample.mean(), color="blue")
```

The two vertical lines are relatively close, so from what you said in the comment section, you wouldn't expect the p-value to be small. You're wrong.

Here, the p-value is about `9.52e-06` if you conduct a one sample t-test for this sample against a population with a mean value of 0.4. In Python:

```
t = scipy.stats.ttest_1samp(sample, pop_mean)
print(t)
TtestResult(statistic=-4.545012045171856, pvalue=9.522320781057063e-06, df=199)
```

You see that we have a *t*-statistic of about `-4.54`. This is from this *t*-statistic and from your sample size that the p-value is calculated. If you draw many random samples (with 200 observations each) from a population with a mean of 0.4, you'll see that it is rare to get a sample with a *t*-statistic of -4.54.

Below is a graph showing the distribution of the *t*-statistic calculated from 10,000 samples (with 200 observations each), drawn randomly from a population with a mean of 0.4. The red line shows where our previous sample with a *t*-statistic of -4.54 would be located, if it belonged to this population of mean 0.4. This is probably this graph you had in mind.

[image: Distribution of the t-statistic for samples drawn randomly from a population with a mean of 0.4. The vertical red line appear at the left tail of the distribution, away from the mean 0.]

You see how unusual it is to get a *t*-statistic of -4.54, if the sample we drawn were coming from a population with mean 0.4. Hence the small p-value we have.

Here is some Python code to replicate the graph above, with the simulation of 10,000 random samples with 200 observations each, taken from a population with mean 0.4:

```
t_stat_list = []
for i in range(10000):
    sample = np.random.normal(loc=0.4, scale=1.0, size=sample_size)
    t_stat = scipy.stats.ttest_1samp(sample, pop_mean).statistic
    t_stat_list.append(t_stat)
    # samps .append(sample.mean())
ax = sns.distplot(t_stat_list)
ax.set_title("""Distribution of the t-statistic for samples
drawn from a population with a mean of 0.4""")
plt.axvline(t.statistic, color="red")
```